# Calculate identifierForVendor from UDID, VendorID &?

Tags: ios

I have the UDID of some devices in the wild.  Unfortunately, they are reporting back using Cordova device.uuid, which is identifierForVendor.

Presumably, I can determine the VendorID as well.

How is identifierForVendor calculated?  I realize there is a third parameter, that I would have to sweep.

Comment: identifierForVendor is an opaque value that can change at any time and is not supposed to have any connection to the UDID. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Noah, Unfortunately, the user recorded UDIDs of the iPads in use, but not the identifierForVendor.  Therefore, we are trying to correlate reported data to physical devices.

However, I hoping that although identifierForVendor is opaque, it can be back calculated given the suite inputs.